# Estimating the Size of a Table

Tags: sql-server, database

I want to estimate a table size.
I followed the following links: 
[Heap Size](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189124(v=sql.105).aspx),  [Clustered Index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178085(v=sql.105).aspx)

I was wondering if you could tell me if my calculations are correct:
Assuming: there are 36 columns. 32 are varchar(64), 1 bigint(PK), 1 Datetime, 2 uniqueidentifier

[image]

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server provides a built-in stored procedure that you can run to easily show the size of a table.

```
sp_spaceused ‘Tablename’
```

[sql-server-tablesize](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/database/determine-size-of-a-table-in-sql-server/)

Comment: I'm not trying to figure out what is the size of a specific table after it's in use. I'm trying to figure out what will be the size of the table with the expected number of rows